# Dojo Graph Tooltip Arrow Appears Incorrectly

Tags: graph, tooltip, dojo, dojox.charting

For some reason, the arrow on the tooltip for each graph point appears below the actual label(see image). I have tried doing everything to move it and can not figure out why this is happening. The tooltip is generated automatically by dojo's chart library. It appears fine in the demos.

Does anybody have an idea why?[image: Image of the Broken Tooltip]

EDIT:
I am using Dojo 1.7.2.
The code is question is
this.linePlotName is part of the object that the method below resides in.

```
var anim = new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(newLineChart, this.linePlotName);
```

Comment: could you post the relevant code and the version of dojo that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue after I upgraded my Dojo from 1.6 to 1.7.2, but this issue was actually a bug and it is fixed now in 1.7.3: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15016
Upgrade and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, without seeing what else is going on in your code.  However, it's important to keep in mind that the tooltip's behavior is influenced by the widget/div/frame it's contained in.  If there's not enough room to render the tooltip graphic on top of the plot line, it will be drawn under it.  Try increasing the size of the container the chart is contained in, and try increasing the size of the chart itself, so there's plenty of room above the plot line for the tooltip to appear, or even try just scrolling up/down.  It's best to rule out the easy fixes first. :)  If that doesn't work, please comment, and we can go from there...

Comment: I think it might be a problem with this specific version of Dojo. I remember the markers working correctly when I was using 1.5. Just to be sure, I switched one of the pages to use the nightly build of Dojo and the tooltips worked correctly. I found the bug report for it somewhere as well.